# Google Merchant Account Sign Up without website

Tags: google-play

I don't have a URL to sell apps on the google Play Store, but it won't let me submit. What do I do?

Answer (score 26):

This could be done by adding Google Play website url to your account :D

Reply form support:

> Even if you do not have a website of your own, you can definitely sign up as a Google Play merchant. Since the Play Store will be the website that will host your apps you can use https://play.google.com/store as your Business website on the registration page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your **facebook account URL** or your **developer page on Google play**.
https://www.quora.com/Can-I-setup-a-Google-merchant-account-without-a-business-website